# What is VBA's String Comparison Algorithm?

Tags: string, vba, algorithm, excel

I am attempting to speed up the way my program searches for strings in an array.  So, for example, I am writing a program which searches for the word "test" in a column of 1000 random words.

Currently my program is a simple:

```
If Cells(x,1).Value = "test" Then
...
End If
```

However, here is my idea,

```
If Left(Cells(x,1).Value,1) = "t" Then
If Left(Cells(x,1).Value,2) = "te" Then
... and so on ...
End If
```

But then I began to wonder if when I ask for `VBA` to test to see if the `value = "test"`, does it go through the process I outlined in that second code?  Basically, my question is, is the second code redundant? I am unfamiliar with how VBA inherently looks for entire strings to match.  If someone could shed light on what VBA goes through when I ask it to look for a `Value = "string"` it could really help.  Thanks!

Comment: why don't you just use the `Range.Find` method?

Comment: or `Match` function?  If you're looking at optimization, surely there are better built-in ways than relying on (what appears to be) brute force cellwise iteration.

Comment: Any benefit that might have goes out the window as soon as you start reading the cell repeatedly - the overhead of going to the sheet to read a value is comparatively large, so doing that over repeatedly is not a good direction.

Comment: Your idea of how a search is performed is probably correct. However, you also need to consider if its ANSI, UTF-8, UTF-16 ... etc. You get the picture. Hence the suggestions given here are your best options. Rely on built-in functions.

Comment: Is your question, "what does the compiler do to evaluate stringa=stringb"?

Comment: A large part of the slowness of dealing with each individual cell is that VBA must load all the associated properties (of which there are dozens) of those objects even if all you're doing is looking at the value. Instead, you can actually get Excel to give you a VBA array directly that contains just the values. First, get the entire range you're interested in - `Set rng = Range("B2:B1001")` for example - and then you get the `Value2` property of this range, which is a two dimensional VBA Variant array. You can loop through this much more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

## How to find if a given value exists in a range using [`Range.Find` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx):

```
Dim rng as Range
Dim found as Range
Dim val As String

val = "test" '## Modify as needed
Set rng = Range("A1:A1000") '## Modify as needed
Set found = rng.Find(val)

'The Range.Find method will return a Nothing if the value is not found
If found Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not found!"
Else
    'do something with it...

End If
```

The `Range.Find` method has optional arguments which can be used to specify whole or partial matches, case sensitivity, etc.

## How to find a given value exists in a range using `Match` function.

NB: The `Application.Match` function is similar to the [`WorksheetFunction.Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx) except that if the match is *not found* the `Application` class will return an Error Type (hence the need to define its return value as `Variant`, whereas the `WorksheetFunction` class will *raise* an error).

```
Dim rng as Range
Dim found as Variant
Dim val as String
val = "test" '## Modify as needed
Set rng = Range("A1:A1000") '## Modify as needed
found = Application.Match("test", rng, False)

'The Application.Match function will return an Error Type if the val is not found
If IsError(found) Then
    MsgBox "Not found!"
Else
    'do something with it
End If
```

**Limitations of `Match` function:** The `Match` function only really works for exact matches (using the `False` argument) or *approximate* matches (using the `True`, `msoTrue` or `msoCTrue` arguments) which has some other assumptions built in, namely that the data is sorted). The `Match` function can only be used on a single-column range or a single-row range.